Angular 13 upgrde error :✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode
Building entry point '@famc/shared-components'
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
projects/famc/shared-components/src/lib/inputs/src/components/checkbox/checkbox.component.ts:8:14 - error
NG3001: Unsupported private class FamcCheckBoxComponent. This class is visible to consumers via FamcSharedComponentsModule -> FamcInputsModule -> FamcCheckBoxComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint.
upgrading angular 11 to 17

Are you in fact exporting the checkbox component from the top level entrypoint? Please provide your code so that we can help you properly.
